# How to get other than "conversationUpdate" and "endOfConversation" from MS Bot Framework, Skype For Business

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, skype-for-business

While we did not find solution to [our previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054599/how-to-toubleshoot-configuration-of-ms-bot-framework-and-skype-for-business) about registration of our bot to Skype for Business channel (hereinafter SfB) we attempted to create brand new bot and perform new registration to SfB channel for brand new user. There was no error during the creation and registration process.

At the moment we can read incoming `Activity` in debug mode when attached by Visutal Studio 2017 (Cloud Explorer>Attach Debugger) to bot deployed at Azure but we observe only Activities of Type: "**conversationUpdate**" or "**endOfConversation**" each time we send a message to our bot via SfB.

**UPDATE**

The bot was created and registered using an account that is linked to Azure and MSDN subscription however the account is not part of our Azure Active Directory. The sender and bot account used by SfB are part of our Azure Active Directory.

If I create dedicated Azure Active Directory from Azure portal owned by the account that also owns the bot itself then the comminication via SfB works for accounts created in this dedicated Azure Active Directory.

**END UPDATE**

**What logs or settings at Azure or SfB can we check now to make the communication finally working?**
Are there any special requirements to user that represents the bot that might need to be doublechecked? 
**Are there any additional security settings for the bot if its owner has no rights to Azure Active Directory where bots audience users are defined?**

See example of serialized json activities:

```
{
  "type": "conversationUpdate",
  "id": "6d5f79c9-9a89-4606-92cb-9ead49405865",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-01T14:13:53.3958935Z",
  "serviceUrl": "https://webpooldb40r04.infra.lync.com/platformservice/.../botframework",
  "channelId": "skypeforbusiness",
  "from": { "id": "sip:me@us.com", "name": "LastName, Me" },
  "conversation": { "isGroup": true, "id": "YzkxZDQ2MmQjc2lwOmFmZmJib3RAYmx1ZWxpbmtz..." },
  "recipient": { "id": "sip:ourbot@us.info", "name": "sip:ourbot@us.info" },
  "membersAdded": [],
  "membersRemoved": [ { "id": "sip:me@us.com", "name": "LastName, Me" } ],
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": []
}
```

and

```
{
  "type": "endOfConversation",
  "id": "4b485bcf-59c8-446f-9d56-74dda973db25",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-01T14:13:53.4115031Z",
  "serviceUrl": "https://webpooldb40r04.infra.lync.com/platformservice/.../botframework",
  "channelId": "skypeforbusiness",
  "from": { "id": "sip:ourbot@us.info" },
  "conversation": { "isGroup": true, "id": "YzkxZDQ2MmQjc2lwOmFmZmJib3RAYmx1ZWxpbmtz..." },
  "recipient": { "id": "sip:ourbot@us.info", "name": "sip:ourbot@us.info" },
  "membersAdded": [],
  "membersRemoved": [],
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": []
}
```

Remarks:

1) Bot is registered for more than a week.

2) Our controller contains as few code as possible to avoid any problem that might influence our tests:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                var reply = activity.CreateReply("Reply");
                using (var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(reply.ServiceUrl)))
                {
                    await connectorClient.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

3) Responses are correctly being generated for WebChat channel: [image: WebChat sample text and response]

4) In bot Analytics we see incoming messages and users for both WebChat and SfB[image]

5) If we attempt to respond to Activity of Type "conversationUpdate" or "endOfConversation" anyway then we observe:

```
{"Conversation does not exist"} Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException
```

6) If we try to execute code that creates new conversation then we get:

```
{"BVD operation failed with 404"} Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException
```

Points 5) and 6) are rather expected and are appended merely for illustration

Comment: Were you able to find a reason why issue number 5 in your list occurs. I'm trying to respond to conversationUpdate to greet the user on SfB, but it return the same error  as you specified. {"Error":{"Code":"ServiceError","Message":"Conversation does not exist"}}. But when I send a new message, it responds back with the same conversationId that was passed in the last conversationUpdate event. BTW I use REST api.

Comment: Can you check this out @rudolf_franek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, S4B Bots can only communicate to users in the same domain. Reason is security as bots can identify the identity of the users they are interacting with (user identity is not hashed), and need Tenant Administrator steps before end users can use a bot in a tenant.

Therefore the federation/cross-tenant scenario is not currently supported.

In most cases, it is recommended to create a bot “instance” in each AAD "domain".

Comment: 1) The bot account and the sender of the message are from the same domain - and setting of bot into this domain by powershell works. Just the bot itself is in different subscription owned by user not in this domain. Strange is that the conversation is somehow "created" and "ends" immediately and debug information about the users is correct. 2) create a bot “instance” in each AAD "domain" -> this is how we ended up, however it was not desired scenario because other channels of the bot were already setup and this way we have to migrate the other channels as well.

Comment: Hi rudolf, I think this is a scenario the Bot Service team is considering and I would recommend you to provide your use case as feedback. You may also open a support ticket from the Azure portal to push your feedback through. Although I cannot say whether this will actually be worked or not anytime soon, yours is not the only use case that was pushed through.